# Do we have to change the code at the build time for each different platform in phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

I want to know if I have to change the code while building the application for different platforms in phonegap. Suppose I have created the app which include database,also calling the web service(API),then do all that code changes as we change the platform? Can we have a code that is build one time and that works for all platforms such as android, ios and windows and if it is possible than how?
I want to get clear about phonegap that do we have differnet ways for calling a web service or storing data in database for differnt platforms?
I am using IntelXDK for building phonegap app.

Comment: It's the meaning of cordova and phonegap to share the code for all platforms. Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova (aka PhoneGap) applications are ordinarily implemented as a browser-based WebView within the native mobile platform

1) No need to change your code for each platform .

2) You will have to build your app for each platform like for iOS app in xcode, for android in eclipse or android studio or **[Build on cloud](https://build.phonegap.com/plans)**

3) No need to change web service or storing data in database for differnt platforms, same code you can use for each platform.

**[Read more..](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview)**

Comment: So what if I want to store local data?Does phonegap provide any utility?

Comment: Do i have to use native sdk for each platform while storing local data?

Comment: Yes you can use WebSql or sqlite plugin ..see more http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: Yes, it is Phonegap plugin for iOS see  https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin